# Three 1cm x 2cm metal sheets in my table saw packaging

Tags: table-saw

There are three 1cm x 2cm metal sheets in my DeWalt DW745 table saw packaging; Does anyone know what is that for?

[image: Three 1cm x 2cm metal sheets in my table saw packaging]

Comment: Page 4 of your instruction manual. https://hybrisimages.toolcommerce.com/documents/English/Instruction%20Manual/650150-00,DW745.pdf

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the answer can be found in the manual

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the manual, they are number 6 items, extra guard shims. This implies that one can adjust the spacing of the blade guard when attaching the guard to the table. Did you get a manual with the saw?

Comment: That may have been the nicest way of saying "RTFM" I've ever seen! Well done.

Comment: @FreeMan I believe in "if everything else failed, then read the manual" :D